Excel Form (VBA) How to auto insert data after scan barcode without press the button
I have created an excel form to count inventory using scan barcode to text box. now I have to click button to add new data after scanned and would like to change by auto insert data instead of press the button. Would you please suggest on how to coding? Thank you.
Here is the current command.
Private Sub cmdInsert_Click()

    If Len(Trim(Me.txtData1.Value)) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Please fill Data1", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtData2.Value)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please fill Data2", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry")
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
           
        sh.Range("A" & lastrow).Value = Me.txtData1.Value
        sh.Range("B" & lastrow).Value = Me.txtData2.Value
        sh.Range("C" & lastrow).Value = Me.txtData3.Value
        sh.Range("D" & lastrow).Value = Me.txtData4.Value
      
   Call clear_data

   Call ShowData
End Sub


Your barcode scanner should have the ability to set the character that gets sent after a successful scan (the default on most scanners is TAB, but there should be a sheet of barcodes you can scan to change this).  Set your barcode scanner to send an ENTER and then use the OnChange event to process your data.
